# Creating a column in pandas dataframe based off another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one column contains only strings.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(
  {
    "A": [2,4,7,17,39], 
    "B": ["apple","apple","broccoli","rose","apple"]
  }
)
```

I want to examine this column "B" and look for all the times a string contains a certain part of a word. Then I create a new column "C" that contains a series of strings that say "fruit" whenever "app" is in the row,"flower" for whenever "ros" shows up and vegetable for whenever "brocc" shows up.

The final dataframe will look like:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(
  {
    "A": [2,4,7,17,39], 
    "B": ["apple","apple","broccoli","rose","apple"], 
    "C": ["fruit","fruit", "vegetable", "flower", "fruit"]
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary

```
d = {'apple': 'fruit', 'broccoli': 'vegetable', 'rose': 'flower'}
```

And use it in `map` or `replace`  (map is faster for this):

```
df['B'].map(d)
Out: 
0        fruit
1        fruit
2    vegetable
3       flower
4        fruit
Name: B, dtype: object

df['B'].replace(d)
Out: 
0        fruit
1        fruit
2    vegetable
3       flower
4        fruit
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: I slightly edited the question so that the full name of the entity isn't required. Does this change the answer you provided?

Comment: @John You normally shouldn't change the question in non-trivial ways (especially if you could invalidate answers). Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @John No, this wouldn't work for partial matching. The rule in the question is not very clear. Are the parts of the words determined beforehand? For example are you going to be able to construct a dictionary like this? Or do you want to use this dictionary but return a value if there is a partial match? For the latter, you need to clarify what kind of matching is acceptable. What happens if there is only `o`? Would it be a vegetable or a flower?

Comment: I also agree that a new question would be better for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary as converter an it's `get` method as input for `apply`:

```
converter = {'apple': 'fruit',
             'broccoli': 'veg',
             'rose': 'flower'}

df['C'] = df['B'].apply(converter.get)
print(df)
    A         B       C
0   2     apple   fruit
1   4     apple   fruit
2   7  broccoli     veg
3  17      rose  flower
4  39     apple   fruit
```

In case of the partial matching you would need to change this a little bit:

```
converter = {'app': 'fruit',
             'brocc': 'vegetable',
             'ros': 'flower'}

df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda original: next(val for key, val in converter.items() if key in original))
print(df)
    A         B          C
0   2     apple      fruit
1   4     apple      fruit
2   7  broccoli  vegetable
3  17      rose     flower
4  39     apple      fruit
```

The `next(val for key, val in converter.items() if key in original)` will give you the value from the dictionary for the first found key that is in the "row".